# UICollectionView App crashes if scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i am facing an issue. I created an `UICollectionView` and if i scroll that much, that i cannot see the first row anymore, then the App crashes. I really do not know how to solve this. This is the part of my App where i create the `CollectionView`. The content of the Cells are images, which are holding a thumbnail of all videos of my movies synchronized with iTunes. Everything is working, but not the scrolling over more then 1 row.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return itemList.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    // we're going to use a custom UICollectionViewCell, which will hold an image and its label

    //NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
    VPCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];


    // make the cell's title from title of current MPMediaItem

    MPMediaItem *item = [itemList objectAtIndex:cellMediaItemCounter];
    NSString* title = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", title];

    NSNumber *duration=[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
    double seconds = duration.doubleValue;

    int secondsInt = round(seconds);
    int minutes = secondsInt/60;
    secondsInt -= minutes*60;

    cell.durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2i:%.2i", minutes, secondsInt];

    // load the thumbnail for this cell

    NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:13.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

    //set thumbnail to cell image
    cell.image.image = thumbnail;

    cellMediaItemCounter++;
    //pause initiated player (to get thumbnail), if not it's playing in background
    player=nil;
    return cell;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Solution from @Vame works perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like an index out of range exception. Put this:

```
MPMediaItem *item = [itemList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

instead of

```
MPMediaItem *item = [itemList objectAtIndex:cellMediaItemCounter];
```

Comment: Or perhaps `indexPath.item`.

Comment: Thanks! I works fine now. The problem was really an "index out range exception".